# Why to write custom logger in Android

Tags: android

Heard a few times that every `Android` project starts from writing a custom logger. Why do we need it? Is basic logger which ships with `Android SDK` is bad?

Comment: "Heard a few times that every Android project starts from writing a custom logger" -- citations, please. If you give us links to these places, we may be able to get more context about their comments and can explain their recommendations to you.

Comment: @CommonsWare didn't attach this because it's in Russian. https://twitter.com/mobileunderhood/status/1095319842549309441 - it's a channel where popular Russian mobile devs share their experience with others. So, it's said that every C++ project starts from writing custom `string` and `Android` from a custom logger.  Saw similar things lots of time but can't remind another sources.

Comment: that is totally opinion-based, therefore - off-topic on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Logger (`Log`) is not bad. But there is some case where you need, for instance, send logs into the server or separate **Debug** and **Production** logs using `Crashlytics` instead of `Log.*(...)`.

Comment: [Example of custom logger](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceCompleteFragment/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/common/logger)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom logger. `Log.d()` works just fine for standard purposes.